# How to hide first level span element by CSS ">" selector

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code

```css
.wrapper.mini-menu .sidebar-nav li > span{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper mini-menu">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                    <span>Hide Item1</span>
                    <i class="fa arrow pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                            <span>Show Item 1</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                            <span>Show Item 2</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#item1">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                    <span>Hide Item2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item1">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                    <span>Hide Item3</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide hide `item1`, hide `item2` and hide `item3`. But I don't want to hide `show` items. If I don't use  `>` selector it hides all span elements. How to select only those item by CSS `>` selector?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/b6cwsdqu/ ?

Comment: Yes now its working fine. Thanks @DaniP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your current CSS selector is saying is:

Hide all `span`s that are children of `li` that are descendants of `.sidebar-nav`. If you only want to target first level `li` elements do this instead:

```
.wrapper.mini-menu .sidebar-nav > li > a > span {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it hides all span

Answer (score 1):

Look:

```css
    .wrapper.mini-menu .sidebar-nav > li > a{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper mini-menu">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
                    <span>Hide Item1</span>
                    <i class="fa arrow pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                            <span>Show Item 1</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                            <span>Show Item 2</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
      
            <li>
                <a href="#item1">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
                    <span>Hide Item2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item1">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> 
                    <span>Hide Item3</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You select a span standing right after the .fa-user-plus icon with the **[+](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)** selector , but not so sure this what you look for ?

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
span {
  display:none;
  }
.fa.fa-user-plus + span{
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper mini-menu">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
                    <span>Hide Item1</span>
                    <i class="fa arrow pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                            <span>Show Item 1</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                            <span>Show Item 2</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
      
            <li>
                <a href="#item1">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
                    <span>Hide Item2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item1">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> 
                    <span>Hide Item3</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```